# Where can I find a list of key codes for use with Cocoa's NSEvent class?

Tags: cocoa, events, keyboard

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of the available key codes that can be used with Cocoa's `NSEvent` class. The `NSEvent` class has a `keyCode` property, which is defined as `unsigned short`. The following code, when placed in an appropriate UI object, will echo the key codes as they are pressed:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [theEvent keyCode]);
}
```

From this code, I can easily see which codes match certain keys, but I would like to find an official document somewhere that lists all of them. I expected Apple to have a header file somewhere that looked like this:

```
enum {
    ...
    NSKeyCodeLeftArrow = 123,
    NSKeyCodeRightArrow = 124,
    ...
};
```

But if there is one, I have yet to find it.

Comment: Note that media keys and keys like "Home", "Internet" on massive keyboards are dealt with by NSSystemDefined events, rather than ordinary key events. That accounts for the missing keycodes for those keys (Windows has keycodes for all keys, and there are X11 keysyms for them too, but Mac's keycodes for keyboard events don't seem to cover all those keys).

Comment: [W3C DOM Level 3 KeyboardEvent code Values](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-code-20150428/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no enum or list of key codes. However, to get similar behavior, you can call [interpretKeyEvents:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1531599-interpretkeyevents:) in keyDown: which will call appropriate action methods, all of which are documented in NSResponder (e.g. [moveLeft:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder), [insertTab:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/insertTab:), etc.)

Comment: That's incredibly handy. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now that I know what to look for, I found a link which describes all of those NSResponder methods in terms of the default key combinations that invoke them: http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html

Comment: That page is very useful. Nice find! :)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 33):

[Here you go.](http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2007-05-22/virtual-key-codes) It's a map of all the virtual key-codes on the US extended keyboard layout, from the old Inside Macintosh: Text. Most of the key codes are still currently, although I suspect that the very newest Apple keyboards—those with media keys—may have changed a few of the function keys.

Note: ISO and non-extended keyboards may have different key codes for some keys. If you have such a keyboard, try [Peter Maurer's Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) application. His site is down, so [here's my copy](http://boredzo.org/stuph/keycodes-1.0.1.dmg).

Comment: Thank you. That certainly explains why there is no new table available. FTA: *Mac OS X uses the same virtual key-codes that it used for the legendary Apple Extended Keyboard. Thus, the table in Inside Macintosh: Text still applies.*

Comment: I wrote the article. ☺ It's true of US extended keyboards (and is *definitely* true of my keyboard, since it *is* an Apple Extended Keyboard II), but may not be true for non-extended and/or non-US keyboards. I should add a note to the post that I haven't checked either case.

Comment: Ah, so you did! Great stuff. I can't believe you are (still?) using that keyboard. :) Doing some reading online, there appears to be something close to a *religion* based around that model. What makes it so much better than anything currently on the market? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Yup, I'm still using it. Its advantages include the feel and sound of the keys, the durability (this keyboard is going on 20 years old), the adjustability, the hardware-controllable modifier lights (http://youtube.com/watch?v=G5G-hlG2kpA), the nubs on which to hang a function-key definition template (http://boredzo.org/aek2-overlay/)—lots of little things. The only keyboard with more fervent devotees is IBM's Model M, which another company still makes (http://pckeyboard.com/). I've yet to own one, but I have typed on one and that one is pretty damned good, too.

Comment: Interesting. My first Mac was a Performa 6300, and I'm pretty sure it came with that keyboard. If my parents still have it in their basement, I'll give it a try for old times sake.

Comment: Nope. The Performa 6300 came with the AppleDesign Keyboard, which is the Apple Extended Keyboard II's evil nemesis. It was the first dome-switch keyboard Apple produced, and the mushiest keyboard ever.

Comment: Dead link: boredzo.org

Comment: @JaredBeck: Only mostly dead. It'll be back once I send an email to my host about a database import.

Comment: In the meantime: http://web.archive.org/web/20130314125339/http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2007-05-22/virtual-key-codes

Comment: And the original site is not down. Maybe he mixed up the inks?

Answer (score 13):

To include HIToolbox/Events.h (as mentioned in berrange's answer) in XCode 4 you just need to go to Link Binaries with Libraries and add the Carbon framework (which includes HIToolbox) and then import the main Carbon header in the file where you are checking the keyCodes.

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>
```

It took me a second to figure out that I couldn't import HIToolbox/Events.h directly so I thought I'd post this in case it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks - if you find this question, this is the solution to use.

Comment: There's no need to link with the Carbon framework to use those enums.  It's enough to add the header to be able to use them for this particular case (unless of course you need to make use of other Carbon functions).

Comment: It's worth noting (since the question was about `NSEvent`) that in addition to the keycodes in `HIToolbox/Events.h`, you may also want the unicode code points defined in AppKit's `NSEvent.h`, such as `NSRightArrowFunctionKey`, as these are used to set the `characters` property of `NSEvent`.

Answer (score 8):

For Swift, import `Carbon.HIToolbox.Events` and then use the constants directly:

```swift
import Carbon.HIToolbox.Events

let keyCode = kVK_ANSI_A
```

For a list of all codes, go to the definition of `Carbon.HIToolbox.Events`:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

According to this forum topic, the constants are available in HIToolbox/Events.h

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=780577

They have conveniently copy+pasted the entire set of constants into the forum too. Otherwise the header is available here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```