# What object to use for special text-editing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield, nstextview

i need a special text-field that should do the following stuff:

- multiline
- tab key support
- send action when enter key gets pressed
- alt+enter for new line
- shift+enter for new line

i don't know what to use.

NSTextView looks good, but i can not set an action on enter and pressing the enter key results in a new line

NSTextField has no tab-key support and shift-enter is not working.

any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to subclass `NSTextView` to get the functionality that you want. Here is a quick example:

> **MyTextView.h**

```
@interface MyTextView : NSTextView
{
    id target;
    SEL action;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id target;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL action;
@end
```

> **MyTextView.m**

```
@implementation MyTextView

@synthesize target;
@synthesize action;

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if ([theEvent keyCode] == 36) // enter key
    {
        NSUInteger modifiers = [theEvent modifierFlags];
        if ((modifiers & NSShiftKeyMask) || (modifiers & NSAlternateKeyMask))
        {
            // shift or option/alt held: new line
            [super insertNewline:self];
        }
        else
        {
            // straight enter key: perform action
            [target performSelector:action withObject:self];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // allow NSTextView to handle everything else
        [super keyDown:theEvent];
    }
}

@end
```

Setting the target and action would be done as follows:

```
[myTextView setTarget:someController];
[mytextView setAction:@selector(omgTheUserPressedEnter:)];
```

For more details on key codes and the full suite of `NSResponder` messages like `insertNewline:`, see the excellent answers to my question about `NSEvent` keycodes: [Where can I find a list of key codes for use with Cocoa's NSEvent class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2080312/33686)

Comment: From what you describe, you should only need to override insertNewline: and add action and target properties. In insertNewline:, call the super implementation if shift or option are being held down and perform the action if they aren't.

Comment: thanks looks good. i'm wondering whats the best way to perform a action. can you provide an example how this could be done? f.e. `[mytextfield setAction:@selector(xyz:)]`

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: you may be right, but how would you test for the shift and option modifiers from within insertNewline? In keyDown, you have access to the event object.

Comment: You can get the event from insertNewline: using [NSApp currentEvent] or [[self window] currentEvent]

Comment: works great! thanks for the hint with the selector/target. i'm not shure what the improvement of ughoavgfhw's answer would be?