# Handling keyboard events in AppKit with Swift

Tags: swift, appkit

I have a custom NSView subclass that needs to handle some keyboard events. In Objective-C, I might handle it like this:

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
{
    unichar ch = [[event charactersIgnoringModifiers] characterAtIndex:0];

    if (ch == NSUpArrowFunctionKey && (event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask)) {
        // Scroll to top
        return;
    }
    else if (ch == NSDownArrowFunctionKey && (event.modifierFlags & NSCommandKeyMask)) {
        // Scroll to bottom
        return;
    }

    switch (ch) {
        case NSRightArrowFunctionKey:
            // Select the current row
            return;
        case ' ':
            // Scroll down one page
            return;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [super keyDown:event];
}
```

In Swift, however,`characterAtIndex:` returns a `unichar`, while `NSUpArrowFunctionKey: Int` and `" ": String` (or `Character`). It's not clear to me how to convert a unichar to a `String` or `Character`.

I got this working, but it feels like an ugly workaround. Is there a better way?

```
func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let char = Int(theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers.utf16[0])  // <----- This seems ugly
    let hasCommand = (theEvent.modifierFlags & .CommandKeyMask).value != 0

    switch char {

        case NSUpArrowFunctionKey where hasCommand == true:
            // Scroll to top
            break

        case NSDownArrowFunctionKey where hasCommand == true:
            // Scroll to bottom
            break

        case NSRightArrowFunctionKey where hasCommand == true:
            // Select the current row
            break

        case Int(" ".utf16[0]):   //  <---- Surely there's a better way of doing this?
            // Scroll down one page
            break

        default:
            super.keyDown(theEvent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers == String(NSUpArrowFunctionKey)` never returns true, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Nicest thing I can come up with is to use an actual Character as the case selector: that lets you compare with `Character(" ")` for the space key, for example. You still have to do something fairly ugly to convert the integer key codes for matching, though. Best I could find was to use `Character(UnicodeScalar(NSUpArrowFunctionKey))` to turn the constants into real Swiftian Characters. Perhaps what this really needs is more Swiftian versions of the constants, rather than anything else...

Answer (score 18):

Let the oft-overlooked `interpretKeyEvents()` do the messy bits for you. It knows about all sorts of keys, including arrow keys:

```
override func keyDown(event: NSEvent) {
    interpretKeyEvents([event]) // calls insertText(_:), moveUp(_:), etc.
}

override func insertText(insertString: AnyObject) {
    let str = insertString as! String
    switch str {
    case " ":
        println("User hit the spacebar.")
    default:
        println("Unrecognized input: \(str)")
    }
}

override func moveUp(sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Up arrow.")
}

override func moveLeft(sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Left arrow.")
}

override func deleteBackward(sender: AnyObject?) {
    println("Delete.")
}
```

The [NSResponder Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/) section Responding to Action Messages lists these and other methods for handling keyboard events.

Answer (score 10):

Why not use **extensions**?

```
extension NSEvent {

    var character: Int {
        // Note that you could also use Int(keyCode)
        return Int(charactersIgnoringModifiers.utf16[0])
    }

}
```

---

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {
    switch theEvent.character {
        case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
            println("up!")
        case 0x20:
            println("spacebar!")
        default:
            super.mouseDown(theEvent)
    }
}
```

Also, note that, as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2080324) answer, there is no public enum that defines all the key codes for every key. It's easiest to simply test what value it is with a `println()` and then use that value in the switch statement.

---

### Edit

Or you could also extend the Character class

```
import Foundation
extension Character {

    var keyCode: Int {
        return Int(String(self).utf16[String.UTF16View.Index(0)])
    }

}
```

and test for it like this

```
case Character(" ").keyCode: // Spacebar
    println("spacebar!")
```

Comment: `NSEvent.keyCode` is different thing with function key unicode constants. It's a code mapped to hardware key rather than a semantic unicode character. For example, it reports `126` for `NSUpArrowFunctionKey` (defined as `0xF700` under *Function-Key Unicodes* section) in my keyboard. Don't use `keyCode` to compare function key unicode.

Comment: He's not using `NSEvent.keyCode`. The method name is a bit unfortunate, but the extension is supposed to be used with the switch statement he suggested, which matches up correctly.

Answer (score 5):

OSX handles key-events using at least two different layers.

- `keyCode`. I believe this is a code mapped to each hardware keyboard key.
- Unicode. Predefined Unicode code-point mapped to a semantic virtual key.

You need to use Unicode key to process user events properly.
You can take the Unicode code-point from the event object like this.

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s   =   theEvent.charactersIgnoringModifiers!
    let s1  =   s.unicodeScalars
    let s2  =   s1[s1.startIndex].value
    let s3  =   Int(s2)
    switch s3 {
    case NSUpArrowFunctionKey:
        wc1.navigateUp()
        return
    case NSDownArrowFunctionKey:
        wc1.navigateDown()
        return
    default:
        break
    }
    super.keyDown(theEvent)
}
```

Take care that `unicodeScalars` is not randomly accessible, so you need to use explicit index object --- `startIndex`.